# Google Spreadsheet parsing

Tags: html, html-table, google-sheets

I am publishing Google Spreadsheet table via **File -> Publish to the Web** ... [Example published table here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSRViwajj_QY5BxQktsvE6_Gy_Ucn8pKgbasyQe7CosIbSbrgX4mCFCQqqvtHiPF0q3D3BH6564-Fzp/pubhtml?gid=472209957&single=true).

From this shared link I am parsing out a blank HTML table structure and display it on our website. I am removing all inline styles applied by Google.

Anyone knows if it is possible to:

1. Apply custom CSS class to cells inside Spreedheets that would google apply to the published HTML table?
2. Is it possible to defina a row inside a spreadsheet that would google publish as a `<thead><tr><th></th></tr></thead>`. For example I would like the first row to be a table header instead of table body.

Or any workarounds how to effectively style this table.

Comment: How do you insert the spreadsheet in your webpage, with an iFrame?

Comment: @FrankGroot I have made my own API that parses the Google spreedsheet table in PHP. My parser for above table returns JSON with a parsed HTML table. See here: http://api.lastapp.xyz/api/parse-table/?url=https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSRViwajj_QY5BxQktsvE6_Gy_Ucn8pKgbasyQe7CosIbSbrgX4mCFCQqqvtHiPF0q3D3BH6564-Fzp/pubhtml?gid=472209957&single=true

Comment: Not sure I understand what apps-script web app is. I could use a Sheet API yes but I found it overly complicated so I tried the easy way.

Comment: Hmm very interesting. Where do I create these templates?

Comment: I created a webapp some time back, where I called in a function from app script which was reading through an array from the spreadsheet and was generating a string with <table>, <tr>, and <td> tagging.